# Multiple Inner Joins Error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am attempting a select query pulling information from 5 different tables and I am getting errors in the from part. I have tried several variations of the code and nothing is working. Below is the code and error.

```
SELECT incident.incidentowner, 
       incident.qualitymember, 
       incident.purchasingmember, 
       incident.additionalmember, 
       incident.customername, 
       incident.customercontact,
       incident.incidentid, 
       incident.stockcode, 
       incident.incidentdate,
       incident.stocksupplier,
       incident.customeraccountno,
       incident.supplydate,
       incident.incidentsite,
       incident.depot, 
       incident.samplesent,
       incident.quantity, 
       incident.incidentvalue, 
       incident.branchtransfer,
       incident.hireorsale,
       incident.quarantined,
       incident.returnedtosupplier,
       incident.replacedbysupplier,
       incident.creditedbysupplier,
       incident.incidentdescription,
       containment.containment,
       containment.containmentdate,
       rootcause.rootcause,
       rootcause.rootcausedate,
       correctiveaction.correctiveaction,
       correctiveaction.correctiveactiondate,
       validation.validation,
       validation.director,
       validation.validationdate 
FROM Incident 
INNER JOIN containment ON 
      incident.incidentid = containment.incidentid
INNER JOIN rootcause ON
      incident.incidentid = rootcause.incidentid
INNER JOIN correctiveaction ON
      incident.incidentid = correctiveaction.incidentid
INNER JOIN validation ON
      incident.incidentid = validation.incidentid
WHERE Incident.IncidentID = @incidentid
```

this returns the following error

```
 Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression
'incident.incidentid = containment.incidentid INNER JOIN rootcause ON
 incident.incidentid = rootcause.incidentid INNER JOIN correctiveaction ON 
 incident.incidentid = correctiveaction.incidentid INNER JOIN validation ON       
 incident.incidentid = validation.inci'.
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added

Comment: Doesn't Access need some extra parentheses when multiple joins?

Comment: @jarlh so it does, never know that thanks.

Comment: That's what the query designer is for.

Answer (score 1):

extra parantheses were needed, thanks microsoft

```
FROM (((Incident 
INNER JOIN containment ON 
  incident.incidentid = containment.incidentid)
INNER JOIN rootcause ON
  incident.incidentid = rootcause.incidentid)
INNER JOIN correctiveaction ON
  incident.incidentid = correctiveaction.incidentid)
INNER JOIN validation ON
  incident.incidentid = validation.incidentid
```